# Geocoding Intersections of San Francisco

Tags: python, geocoding

I have a list of intersections in San Francisco. I would like to convert it from street names (e.g. 15th Street and Mission Street) to latitude and longitude.

I've tried some of the services recommended in other stackoverflow and quora questions but haven't been able to get accurate geocodes.

Tried:
Bing API at GPSVisualizer.com - accuracy off by several streets

Geonames - has an API for 'finding nearest intersections ' but you need to provide the latitude longitude combination.

Any other services which will provide an accurate geocode and can be used in a python script for about 100-200 addresses.

Comment: I am not sure if there is something in python that can do that and if you have the liberty to use R, there is a package in R called "ggmap" that has a function called geocode(). You feed it the address and if google has the address in its database, it returns the (lat,long) for that address. Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, restricted to Python for now. Also, google might have geocodes for addresses, but not specifically for intersections. So that is where google api fails.

Comment: Well, it goes to the fourth or fifth decimal place for latitudes and longitudes. Used it for one of my class projects. I found an alternative in python here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder. You can get the la,lo combination and  pass it to geonames like you said.